# Solve this equation

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, algebra-precalculus, analysis, systems-of-equations

I have the conditions $$1 = e^{\alpha-1} \sum_{n=1}^M e^{\beta E_n + \gamma N_n} $$
$$\langle E \rangle = e^{\alpha-1} \sum_{n=1}^M E_n e^{\beta E_n + \gamma N_n} $$
$$\langle N \rangle = e^{\alpha-1} \sum_{n=1}^M N_n e^{\beta E_n + \gamma N_n} $$

and from this I want to determine what $\alpha, \beta, \gamma$ are in terms of all the other variables. Is this possible in this generality?

Edit: Since all other variables are positive, taking the log might help.

Comment: What means $\langle E \rangle$ and $\langle N \rangle $ ?

Comment: they are just real positive numbers

Comment: $\alpha$ is determined by the first equation, so the problem is, given $f(\beta, \gamma)=\sum_{n=1}^{M}e^{\beta E_n + \gamma N_n}$, that is convex to find it's Legendre Transform. Could help?

Comment: @GGG actually no, could you elaborate on this (maybe by posting an answer)?

Comment: I don't have an answer, since I think that $\beta$ and $\gamma$ are not in general simple funcion of $\langle E \rangle$ and $\langle N \rangle$ as well as $E_n$ and $N_n$. One can see that $\langle e^{1- \alpha}E \rangle = \frac{\partial f}{\partial \beta}$ and $\langle e^{1- \alpha}N \rangle = \frac{\partial f}{\partial \gamma}$ so the problem is to invert $\nabla f = (\langle e^{1- \alpha} E \rangle, \langle e^{1- \alpha} N \rangle)$. The inverse function is the Legendre transform of $f$ which is well defined thanks to the convexity of $f$.